# VisualBrush Fill in Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, app.xaml

I want this type, which I created in a XAML file, of button to be a style in the App.XAML.

```
<Button Width="25" Height="25" ToolTip="Add" Command="{Binding CanAdd}" Padding="0">
    <Rectangle Width="15" Height="15">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_add}"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</Button>
```

Updated my code on the answer of @Ash, which doesn't give me any errors but the button stays blank.
In my App.XAML I have this:

```
        <VisualBrush x:Key="Add"
                     Visual="{StaticResource appbar_add}" />

        <!--Button Add-->
        <Style TargetType="Button"
               x:Key="AddButton"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource SmallButton}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                    Value="Add" />
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                    <Setter Property="Fill"
                            Value="{StaticResource Add}">
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is a Visual with `appbar_add` key in Resources, declare a VisualBrush using that Visual and use brush everywhere:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Border x:Key="appbar_add">
        <TextBlock Text="+"/>
    </Border>

    <VisualBrush x:Key="appbar_addBrush" 
                 Visual="{StaticResource appbar_add}"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

```
<Rectangle Width="15" Height="15" 
           Fill="{StaticResource appbar_addBrush}"/>
```

Comment: @Hypenate, please try my example alone to make sure it is working. VisualBrush is used in Rectangle style, which is declared in Button style Resources. How are Rectangle and Button related? does Button contains Rectangle in Template or what?

Comment: I got it from MahApps http://mahapps.com/guides/icons-and-resources.html  The error I get with your code is: 'System.Windows.Media.VisualBrush' is not a valid value for property 'Visual'

Comment: If I leave the brush out and I just set the Fill Property to Green it still stays blank